# Passing session among pages

Tags: php, session

I am going to pass the variables from the previous page to the current page using session with the code below:

Previous page :

```
<?php   

session_start();
$job_remarks = 'ASAS'; 

$_SESSION["ref"] = $job_remarks ;
echo  $_SESSION["ref"] ; 

..
<form id="employee" name="employee" method="post" action="nextapge.php">  
<input type="submit" value="Apply Now">
```

Current Page: (nextpage.php)

```
<?php   

session_start();

$refernce = isset($_POST['ref']) ? $_POST['ref'] : $_SESSION["ref"];

$refernce  =   $_SESSION["ref"];
    echo $refernce;
```

It works in the locahost but not in the web host. What would cause it to fail on the web host's server?

Comment: `$job_source_link` isn't being set anywhere...

Comment: Could you explain what isn't working on the host server? Error Message? Empty String? Something else?

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry for my typo

I am sure the session variable must be able to ass from one page to another page, but not in the web server. Moreover, I use filezilla client to upload the websites through ftp

Comment: typo??  action="nextapge.php">

Comment: check for white space before and after <?php ?> . Also run this code with error_reporting(-1); To find out the warning/errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php